# Will adding indexes to SQL Server temp tables prevent concurrent processes running?

Tags: sql-server

Will adding indexes to SQL Server temp tables prevent concurrent processes running?

It seems it does ..

i.e. a process has code like:

```
CREATE TABLE #HRF605_Part1_Raw_Data 
(
    MemberNo                    INTEGER   NOT NULL,
    PersonID                    INTEGER   NOT NULL,
    Gender                      CHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
    Age                         INTEGER   NOT NULL,
    Movement_Reason             CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    ProductLevel                CHAR(50)  NULL,
    PolicyTreatmentType         CHAR(50)  NULL,
    StateID                     CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    IsOverseas                  CHAR(30)  NULL,
    HospWaitExemptionUsedDate   CHAR(30)  NULL,
    HospWaitExemptionUsedStatus CHAR(30)  NULL,
    JoinDate                    DATETIME  NULL,
    IsHosCover                  CHAR(30)  NULL,
    HealthTermSuspID            CHAR(5)   NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [XPKHRF605Part1RawData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MemberNo] ASC, [PersonID] ASC, 
                               [Movement_Reason] ASC, [StateID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If I run the process with a large date range and no filters and it takes 3 minutes .. and I want to run the same process with a filter at the same time so that process takes a few seconds, however, I get message:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Procedure ..., Line 114 [Batch Start Line 0]
> There is already an object named 'XPKHRF605Part1RawData' in the database.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ..., Line 114 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

So if index names have to be unique even for temp objects then this means the process is single user at a time for the database ..

i.e. only one user can run just one of these processes at any given time ..

I think the answer to this question is simply 'Yes' but wondered if any other ideas .. I guess I could add some timestamp type of text part to the end of the index name. Do other people do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query, you are giving a name to the constraint explicitly so SQL Server returns an error. To overcome this problem you need to avoid giving a name to your primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE #HRF605_Part1_Raw_Data 
(
    MemberNo                    INTEGER   NOT NULL,
    PersonID                    INTEGER   NOT NULL,
    Gender                      CHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
    Age                         INTEGER   NOT NULL,
    Movement_Reason             CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    ProductLevel                CHAR(50)  NULL,
    PolicyTreatmentType         CHAR(50)  NULL,
    StateID                     CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    IsOverseas                  CHAR(30)  NULL,
    HospWaitExemptionUsedDate   CHAR(30)  NULL,
    HospWaitExemptionUsedStatus CHAR(30)  NULL,
    JoinDate                    DATETIME  NULL,
    IsHosCover                  CHAR(30)  NULL,
    HealthTermSuspID            CHAR(5)   NULL,

    ---CONSTRAINT [XPKHRF605Part1RawData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MemberNo] ASC, [PersonID] ASC, 
                               [Movement_Reason] ASC, [StateID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In this way, SQL Server will create a unique name for every primary key for the seperated sessions temp table.

```
use tempdb
go

select * from sys.indexes
where object_id in (select tbl.object_id from sys.tables tbl where name like '#HRF605%' )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this reply .. This helps ! .. Will try this approach ..

Comment: Also considered having datetimestamp in index name, have to build statement in a variable and use exec statement ..

Comment: Seems to only be an issue with CONSTRAINT and PRIMARY KEY on temp tables .. i.e. CREATE INDEX statements don't seem to incur this error ... somehow ..